# Radio streaming WindowsPhone Application

Tags: c#, windows, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I want to create a simply Windows Phone app which will stream a radio on click, but I have no idea how to make it. I was trying to set an IP address into source of Media Element and the make a method that will play it on click, but it doesn't work. I really want to make this work, any suggestions, please?

Here is xaml code:

```
 <MediaElement AutoPlay="False" Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="422,424,0,0" Name="mediaElement1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Source="http://94.23.22.181:9012" Volume="100" />
```

And c# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement1.Play();
    }
```

Comment: please add code with what you've tried

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post

Comment: I also have a m3u file but it also doesn't work